# There is a fireball class function that when I spam "f" it remains in place

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-physics

I am setting up a game were the main character spits fireballs at is enemies. When I spam the <kbd>f</kbd> key, when the fireball has used up its four seconds, it remains at the end of the screen.

I have not tried anything to solve this problem. This is because I have no clue of how to even start to solve this problem.

```py
#Importing Modules
from random import randint
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import sys
import os
from time import sleep

# intalize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set Up Screen
x_size = 1200
y_size = 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((x_size, y_size))

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img_folder = os.path.join(game_folder, 'images')
player_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'happy_face.png')).convert()
food_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'food.png')).convert()
BAD_food_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'bad_food.png')).convert()
fire_ball_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'fire_ball.png')).convert()
enemy_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, 'enemy.png')).convert()

# Varible Used "while" Loop
done = False


# Setting Caption of Pygame Tab
pygame.display.set_caption("Block Rush Game")

# Colors
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
Lime = (0,255,0)
Yellow = (255,255,0)
Aqua = (0,255,255)
Magenta = (255,0,255)
Silver = (192,192,192)
Gray = (128,128,128)
Maroon = (128,0,0)
Olive = (128,128,0)
Purple = (128,0,128)
Teal =  (0,128,128)
Navy = (0,0,128)

WIDTH = 50
HEIGHT = 50


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = player_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x_size // 2, y_size // 2)
        self.rect.x = x_size / 2
        self.rect.y = y_size / 2
    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += 20
    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x += -20
    def move_up(self):
        self.rect.y += -20
    def move_down(self):
        self.rect.y += 20

    def grow(self):
        width, height = self.image.get_size()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (int(width + 20),int(height + 20)))
        self.rect = self.rect.inflate(20,20)
    def anti_grow(self):
        width, height = self.image.get_size()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (int(width - 20), int(height - 20)))
        self.rect = self.rect.inflate(-20,-20)
    def super_anti_grow(self):
        width, height = self.image.get_size()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (int(width - 40),int(height - 40)))
        self.rect = self.rect.inflate(-40,-40)
    def super_grow(self):
        width, height = self.image.get_size()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(player_img, (int(width + 40),int(height + 40)))
        self.rect = self.rect.inflate(40,40)

class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = food_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.rect.x = randint(0,x_size*5)
        self.rect.y = randint(0,y_size*5)
    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += -20
    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x += 20
    def move_up(self):
        self.rect.y += 20
    def move_down(self):
        self.rect.y += -20

class BAD_Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = BAD_food_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.rect.x = randint(-x_size*2.5,x_size*2.5)
        self.rect.y = randint(0,y_size*5)
    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += -20
    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x += 20
    def move_up(self):
        self.rect.y += 20
    def move_down(self):
        self.rect.y += -20

class FireBall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = fire_ball_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.rect.x = x_size/2
        self.rect.y = y_size/2
        self.cooldown = 4000
        self.last = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += 20

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = enemy_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.rect.x = randint(-x_size*2.5,x_size*2.5)
        self.rect.y = randint(0,y_size*5)
    def move_right(self):
        self.rect.x += -20
    def move_left(self):
        self.rect.x += 20
    def move_up(self):
        self.rect.y += 20
    def move_down(self):
        self.rect.y += -20

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
food_list = []
BAD_food_list = []
enemy_list = []

player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
all_food = []


for i in range(100):
    food = Food()
    all_sprites.add(food)
    food_list.append(food)
    all_food.append(food)
for i in range(100):
    BAD_food = BAD_Food()
    all_sprites.add(BAD_food)
    BAD_food_list.append(BAD_food)
    all_food.append(BAD_food)
for i in range(100):
    enemy = Enemy()
    all_sprites.add(enemy)
    enemy_list.append(enemy)
    all_food.append(enemy)
x_cor_player = x_size*5/2
y_cor_player = y_size*5/2
# Most important code here
fireball = None
while not done:
    clock.tick(120)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                for food in all_food:
                    food.move_up()
                y_cor_player += 20 
                if y_cor_player > y_size * 5:
                    player.move.down
                elif player.rect.centery < y_size // 2:
                    player.move_down()

            if event.key == K_s:
                for food in all_food:
                    food.move_down()
                y_cor_player += -20
                if y_cor_player < 0:
                    player.move_up()
                elif player.rect.centery > y_size // 2:
                    player.move_up


            if event.key == K_a:
                for food in all_food:
                    food.move_left()
                x_cor_player += -20
                if x_cor_player < 0:
                    player.move_right()
                elif player.rect.centerx < x_size // 2:
                    player.move_right()

            if event.key == K_d:
                for food in all_food:
                    food.move_right()
                x_cor_player += 20
                if x_cor_player > x_size * 5:
                    player.move_left()
                elif player.rect.centerx > x_size // 2:
                    player.move_left()

            if event.key == K_f:
                if fireball is None or pygame.time.get_ticks() - fireball.last >= fireball.cooldown:
                    fireball = FireBall()
                    all_sprites.add(fireball)




    for food in food_list:
        if player.rect.colliderect(food):
            food.kill()
            food_list.remove(food)
            all_food.remove(food)
            player.grow()
    for foodz in BAD_food_list:
        if player.rect.colliderect(foodz):
            foodz.kill()
            BAD_food_list.remove(foodz)
            all_food.remove(foodz)
            player.anti_grow()
    for enemy in enemy_list:
        if player.rect.colliderect(enemy):
            enemy.kill()
            enemy_list.remove(enemy)
            all_food.remove(enemy)
            player.super_anti_grow()
        elif fireball != None:
            if fireball.rect.colliderect(enemy):
                enemy.kill()
                enemy_list.remove(enemy)
                all_food.remove(enemy)
                player.super_grow()
    if fireball is not None:
        fireball.move()
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - fireball.last >= fireball.cooldown:
            fireball.kill()
            fireball = None
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

The expected result is that when ever I press the <kbd>f</kbd> key a fireball should spawn and live for 4 seconds. The actual result is that when ever I spam the <kbd>f</kbd> key the fireball stays at the end of the screen and doesn't spawn again.

Comment: Add some `print()`s to the main loop of your program.  Print whether the `fireball` is None.  Print the parts in the time-check of `fireball.cooldown`.  This will allow you to know what execution path is happening inside your code.  I'd guess that the cooldown-timeout is not working.  Probably this check should be moved into a member function of the `Fireball` class, rather than repeated inside the code loops.

Answer (score 0):

First of all note, that the operation [`.kill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) on a [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object, remove the Sprite from all [`Groups`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). So there is no need to remove the Sprite explicitly from a Group, after calling `.kill()`.

Remove the variable `fireball` and all it usage from the entire program. Turen `food_list`, `BAD_food_list`, `enemy_list` and `all_food` to a `pygame.sprite.Group`. add a further Group for the fireballs. Note you've to use `.add` rather than `append` to add objects to the `Group`:

```py
all_sprites   = pygame.sprite.Group()
fire_balls    = pygame.sprite.Group()
food_list     = pygame.sprite.Group()
BAD_food_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_list    = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_food      = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(100):
    food = Food()
    all_sprites.add(food)
    food_list.add(food)
    all_food.add(food)
for i in range(100):
    BAD_food = BAD_Food()
    all_sprites.add(BAD_food)
    BAD_food_list.add(BAD_food)
    all_food.add(BAD_food)
for i in range(100):
    enemy = Enemy()
    all_sprites.add(enemy)
    enemy_list.add(enemy)
    all_food.add(enemy)
```

Adapt the method `move` of the `FireBall` object. `selk.kill()` the object if 4 seconds are elapsed:

```py
class FireBall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    # [...]

    def move(self):
        self.rect.x += 20
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.last >= self.cooldown:
            self.kill()
```

Spawn a new fireball when ever <kbd>f</kbd> is pressed:

```py
while not done:
    clock.tick(120)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:

            # [...]

            if event.key == K_f:
                fireball = FireBall()
                all_sprites.add(fireball)
                fire_balls.add(fireball)
```

Use [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) to identify if the player collides with an object of a Group.
Use [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) to find colliding enemies and fireballs.
When the 3rd respectively 4th parameter is`True` then the object is removed and killed:

```py
while not done:

    # [...]

    for fireball in fire_balls:           
        fireball.move()

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, food_list, True):
        player.grow()

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, BAD_food_list, True):
        player.anti_grow()

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_list, True):
        player.super_anti_grow()

    if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(fire_balls, enemy_list, False, True):
        player.super_grow()

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

If the fireball should be "killed" when hitting an enemy, then you've to pass `True` to the 3rd parameter of `pygame.sprite.groupcollide`:

```py
if pygame.sprite.groupcollide(fire_balls, enemy_list, Treu, True):
    player.super_grow()
```